# Server Policy Based Routing - Remove Packet Mark

Tags: linux, networking, debian, iptables, vpn

I use policy based routing by UID, i.e. processes with a specific UID are forced / tunneled through the VPN. This is done with packet marking as per this link;
[link](https://www.niftiestsoftware.com/2011/08/28/making-all-network-traffic-for-a-linux-user-use-a-specific-network-interface/comment-page-1/). This is all on Debian Stretch (9).

One of the processes tunneled through the VPN (ok its plex) requires access to the plex.tv servers through a non-VPN route to enable 'Remote Access'

I have done this on windows and Debian by simply adding a route from the server --> plex.tv to bypass the VPN. This works if ALL the network traffic is routed via the VPN (i.e. the policy based routing discussed above is not enabled).

When I have the policy based routing enabled the addition of a route doesnt work, I assume because the packets are marked for the UID and therefore routed (by routing table) through the VPN.

I have tried and researched many ideas but nothing that has worked.

1) Is there anyway to 'un-mark' a previously marked packet? I've tried this but couldnt find anyway to un-mark previously marked packets. I thought I could un-mark the packets that were communicating with plex.tv (or its ip address) and they would then not go through the VPN.

2) Im assuming that the marking of the packets and iptables takes precedence over a specified route. Is there a way to make an added route take precedence over rules specified in iptables?

3) I then tried adding an iptables rule at the top of the iptables chain that would accept communication with plex.tv's ip addresses. I thought it might match this rule and exit the chain, but it still seems to apply the rest of the rules.

4) Im thinking maybe something to do with DNAT? but I'm not clued up enough to be able to decipher how to create that rule.

Does anyone reading this have or know of something that would provide a solution. Any assistance would be appreciated.

H

Answer (score -3):

1. "un-mark" - ... --set-mark=0 ...
2. Routing rules (ip rule...) doesn't works with fwmark in Debian... :(
   Try one of RH forks. I've used OpenSUSE.